# PHP and stdin/stdout: where is the extra newline at the beginning coming from?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm using PHP to process some files (run regexp, replace etc) and I've noticed that after processing, there's always a newline at the beginning of all the files I've processed. I've narrowed it down to these few lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
$test = file('php://stdin');

file_put_contents('php://stdout',$test);

?>
```

If you save this and pipe some text through it, you'll notice there's a newline at the beginning of the output. Where is it coming from and how do I get rid of it? Thanks!

PS: PHP version is: PHP 5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  8 2011 19:34:00)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Erm, it's between the shebang line and the `<?php`. I think you can figure out easily enough how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
    <---blank line here
<?php
```

Remember, there's no such thing as a PHP script. There's only files which happen to have PHP code blocks embedded in them. Anything outside of a `<?php ?>` tag set is considered "output" by the PHP engine. That means the blank line between the shebang and the `<?php` opening tag will be output.